Is $f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sin(3^kx)$ continuous? Is it Riemann integrable?
This function is almost like a Weierstrass function, except for $a = 1$, which means that its continuity or integrability are not touched upon by standard proofs of the continuity of the Weierstrass function.

Problem is, does $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sin(3^kx)$ even converge for any $x\ne k\pi$?

It converges for $x = m \pi/3^n$ where $m$ and $n$ are integers.

This series diverges for almost all $x$.  Let $ x = y \pi$ where $y \in [0,1]$ has the base-$3$ expansion $$y = 0.y_1 y_2 y_3 \ldots = \sum_{i=1}^\infty y_i 3^{-i},\ y_i \in \{0,1,2\}$$
Then $$\sin(3^k x) = \pm \sin\left(\sum_{i=k+1}^\infty y_i 3^{k-i} \pi\right)$$
If $y_{k+1} = 1$ we have
$$ \pi/3 \le \sum_{i=k+1}^\infty y_i 3^{k-i} \pi < 2\pi/3 $$
so $|\sin(3^k x)| \ge \sqrt{3}/2 $.  Now almost all $y$ are normal in base $3$, and in particular their base-$3$ expansions have infinitely many $1$'s, and thus your series diverges almost everywhere.

What does it mean for y to be "normal" in base 3?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number

This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the meta announcement regarding quality standards.
